# How to specify a pathname with space in middle to prefix in a makefile

Tags: makefile

In a Makefile for a gnu software distribution, I want to change the value of `prefix` to be a pathname with some whitespaces in the middle.  When I do that, `make` reports error at the assignment to `prefix`. When I double quote the pathname, `make` still doesn't work. How shall I assign the pathname with whitespaces to `prefix`?

Comment: I think you have two distinctive options, more or less: 1. define the corresponding variable in the shell, using ordinary shell methods, quoting and/or backslashing and then pass the variable to make (in the environment or as a parameter). Likely make will use the variable's value as is 2. Inside the Makefile use special workarounds like those defined [here](http://blog.jgc.org/2007/06/escaping-comma-and-space-in-gnu-make.html). They seem cumbersome but nevertheless fun.

Comment: Show the lines that are giving you an error and the error itself. Assigning a value with a space shouldn't cause any problems. **Using** the value with the space might cause issues depending on where you use it.